# Is it possible to use local (unpublished) Node modules in meteor apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In Node, you can require local modules using:

```
var myModule = require('./lib/mymodule.js');
```

Is it possible to do something similar with Meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example to get you started :

Let's install underscore from npm as a local node module in our app server directory :

```
cd server
npm install underscore
```

Then in `server/startup.js` type the following code :

```
var underscoreLatest=Npm.require(process.cwd()+"/app/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js");

Meteor.startup(function(){
  // will display "1.7.0" as of december 2014
  console.log(underscoreLatest.VERSION);
});
```

So basically you need to use `Npm.require` instead of `require` and you have to be careful that the Meteor Node.JS process current working directory is NOT the root of your Meteor project directory, but is instead `".meteor/local/build/programs/server"`.

Comment: Is there an updated answer with Meteor 1.3? I know you can now use import so `var myModule = require('./lib/mymodule.js');` becomes `import myModule from './lib/mymodule.js'; but if you want your module to be also accessible in Meteor packages, it'd be nice to have it work as a npm module entirely